# Heading bug on profiles on Area 51

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, area-51

I have found a bug on Area 51. When we make heading like `#Hello`, visible as:

## Hello

on our profile description, if the text is long then it is going outside its boundry.

#### It is shown here:

[image: Bug on Area 51]

#### And it is also shown in profile page when saved:

[image: Bug on Area 51]

#### And, the page is scroll-able:

[image: Bug on Area 51]

*(Posted here too because [this question on Meta.Area51](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28289/176387) didn't received enough attention)*

#### [Visit my profile on Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/176387/black-thunder?tab=profile)

Comment: Why would anyone want to write such a long series of unbroken text in their profile in the first place? Does it serve a useful purpose? (I recently gave the same comment on a now-deleted post on a similar topic.) If there is a good reason for such a thing, even in an obscure case, then it should be addressed. But is there? The only thing I can think of that would be long enough to trigger the issue is a URL. But URLs can be provided in shorter linked text.

Comment: It's because you are posting from moon. Area 51 is yet to get an update on the Earth. Next build on Moon.

Comment: There was a similar report at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319071/text-in-user-profile-description-should-be-truncated, but it’s deleted now.

Comment: You might want to update the post and include that it's a general issue, and not just area51-specific

Comment: This also happens if the URL on the profile is too long. Except it's the bio itself that gets smaller instead of the right bar getting pushed